# How to use List comprehensions to prepopulate a dict with exceptions on the tiles (if possible)

Tags: python, set, list-comprehension

I learned that I can use list comprehension in python to pre-populate a dict:

```
bounds = {i:1 for i in range(4)}
```

However if I try to add other elements to the dict I have a syntax error:

```
# rise an error
bounds = {i:1 for i in range(4),5:2}
```

Is there an other way to write in a concise way a dict where most of it has the same value and then there are exceptions on the tiles ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a set, but a dict.

You can do the following:

```
>>> x = {i:1 for i in range(4)}
>>> x.update({5:2})
>>> x
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 5: 2}
```

You will, however, *not* be able to do:

```
>>> x = {i:1 for i in range(4)}.update({5:2})
>>> x is None
True
```

Because `update` operates in-place on the dict, and doesn't return (or returns the default None).